# Combining a list of spaced numbers in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have a function that takes a number such as 36, and reverses it to say

```
 '(6 3)
```

Is there anyway to combine that 6 3 to make it one number?

Here is the code that I have written.

```
    (define (number->rdigits num)
      (if (rdigits (/ (- num (mod num 10)) 10)))))


    (define reversible?
      (lambda (n)
        (cond
          [(null? n) #f]
          [else (odd? (+ n (list (number->rdigits n))))])))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using an iterative function that takes each element of the list in turn, accumulating a result. For example:

```
(define (make-number lst)
  (define (make a lst)
     (if (null? lst)
         a
         (make (+ (* 10 a) (car lst)) (cdr lst))))
  (make 0 lst))

(display (make-number '(6 3)))
```

The `make` function uses an accumulator `a` and the rest of the digits in `lst` to build up the final result one step at a time:

```
a = 0
a = 0*10 + 6 = 6
a = 6*10 + 3 = 63
```

If you had more digits in your list, this would continue:

```
a = 63*10 + 5 = 635
a = 635*10 + 9 = 6359
```

---

A less efficient implementation that uses a single function could be as follows:

```
(define (make-number lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (+ (* (expt 10 (length (cdr lst))) (car lst)) (make-number (cdr lst)))))
```

This function needs to calculate the `length` of the remainder of the list for each iteration, as well as calling the `expt` function repeatedly. Also, this implementation is not properly tail recursive so it builds up multiple stack frames during execution before unwinding them all after it reaches its maximum recursion depth.

Comment: Is there any possible way to do this without the use of another function?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do it with one function, but it will be less efficient.

Comment: I guess i'm not really all about efficiency right now, I'm just trying to understand how this works.

Comment: In my opinion, the implementation I've given above (with an internal function) is the easiest to understand. I suggest following through a few iterations with a sample list, to see how it works. If you use `'(6 3 5 9)` then I've pretty much laid out what happens to `a` in my answer.

Comment: Nevertheless, I added a single-function implementation for comparison.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to figure out how to implement it in my main function then! any chance you have a Skype. My midterm is tomorrow and i just need a little help.